# How to store high score inside a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am developing a small game in Java and I am shipping it as a single Jar file. I want to store the high scores/best times for that game somewhere. Instead of storing it in a separate file, I would like to store it in the application itself (inside the Jar) so that its not lost. Is this possible at all ? If so, how to do it programatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java does not give you tools to modify the JARs which are currently run.  If you really want to do it, you have to guess the location of the JAR by yourself (which might reside on a read-only filesystem) and modify it the same way you would modify any archive file.

Bottom line: it's a very bad idea, don't do it!  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194349/what-is-the-proper-way-to-store-apps-conf-data-in-java) for a much more reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is impossible, but storing it in the jar file would make it very complicated. You might also end up with unwanted side effects like "Permission Denied" errors when the jar is owned by another user. Virus scanners might get nervous when they see jar files change without reason, etc....

I would look to the [Preferences API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html) for storing this kind of info.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bad idea to try and store anything in the jar file. Another option is to have a web based service offered to the people playing with your game. The game could connect through a web service to your hosted server and then store everything centrally there. Not sure if it is exactly what you want but it's just an idea. It would also allow people to compete with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Java JAR file is a ZIP-Archive, so you could possibly access it with standard ZIP-Tools and just extract one hisghscores.txt file, modify it and then pack it back again.

Comment: AFAIK Java locks the Jars when running them. So I am not sure if it is possible for a class in the Jar to modify the same Jar at runtime.