# How to save Java properties file to classpath?

Tags: java, classpath, properties-file

To load a properties file from classpath, we can simply do:

```
InputStream inputStream = CommonUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/abc/resources/config.properties");
prop.load(inputStream);
```

After above step, all properties are correctly loaded. But how can I change a property and save it back to the same file on the fly? (Below doesn't work)

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("com/abc/resources/config.properties");
prop.setProperty(key, value);
prop.store(outputStream, null);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Is the file created but is blank?  Do you get an exception?

Comment: Do you mean like updating the jar file that contains the properties file?

Comment: The file locates in the project, as the first part shows, so I use the `class.getClassLoader()` to locate the file. But if I change something and I want to write it back, how can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can not a write to a resource loaded this way.

I would recommend that when your application starts up for the first time it load the defaults properties from the jar file and persist in a well known location.  Then when the application starts it   reads the properties from this location.  [This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194349/what-is-the-proper-way-to-store-apps-conf-data-in-java) has more details about how and where to persist.

Comment: Actually, this is also my solution... but I was wondering if there is any better way other than making a copy of the original properties file. Thanks.